# Unable to print LoggerContext in Play/Scala

Tags: scala, logback

I am following the following tutorial - https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

I want to print `LoggerContext` in my code but I can't figure out how to do so. The  code in the example is in Java and I want to write it in Scala.

```
  // assume SLF4J is bound to logback in the current environment
  LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
  // print logback's internal status
  StatusPrinter.print(lc);
  ...
```

I am facing two issues.
`getILoggerFactory` seem to return `ILoggerFactory` and none of the `print` methods in `StaticPrinter` takes `ILoggerFactory`. Also, `ILoggerFactory` is ann interface with only one method, `getLogger` so I can't get any context information from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analog code in `Scala` looks like:

```
  val lc = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().asInstanceOf[LoggerContext]
  StatusPrinter.print(lc)
```

Casting in `Scala` is done using `.asInstanceOf[Class]` - and is considered an *Anti-Pattern*.